# How to create an onClick method for a button that will send the user to the bottom of the page in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

In my Xamarin mobile app I'm trying to give a button the functionality to send the view to the bottom of the page whenever the button is clicked. As of right now, the button reveals hidden entries and the user must scroll down to see the entries revealed. I want it to snap to the bottom of the page so the user won't have to scroll.

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.scrollview.scrolltoasync?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Use Grid or Absolute Layout. For Grid use it like ``` <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"> <StackLayout> <!-- Put your whole layouts here--> </StackLayout> <Button VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="Button"/> </Grid>  ```

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put your content into a `ScrollView`,and then use `ScrollToAsync` method to scroll to the position of your entry which you want display.

For example :

```
<ScrollView x:Name="scroll">
   <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
       <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="ToBottom"></Button>
        ....... //your content
       <Entry x:Name="entry" Placeholder="entry"></Entry>
   </StackLayout>           
</ScrollView>
```

in your page.xaml.cs :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     scroll.ScrollToAsync(entry,ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
  }
```